# MAMP and composer - Windows

Tags: laravel, composer-php, mamp

I want to use MAMP on my windows machine which i am already doing on one computer. But when i want to install composer to mamp on the computer i get this error:

```
Connection Error [ERR_CONNECTION]: Unable to connect to getcomposer.org

Request to http://getcomposer.org/installer failed with errors:
Failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "SSL" - did you forget to enable it when configured PHP?
```

I have removed the semicolon from `extension=php_openssl.dll` in php.ini-development and php.ini.production.

But im still having same problem :/

Comment: Run `php --ini` to see which ini file is used by the CLI and update that one if it's anything different than the ones you already changed.

Comment: On the command line, what's the output of `php --ri openssl`? Take care that the ini file for CLI may be different from the one that mamp uses. If you know the location of the php binary that MAMP is using run that command from there.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the dll files in your PHP directory.  In my PHP install folder the dll is in the ext folder.  So in the ini files I added ext\ in front of the dll.